# Error CDialog "not a class or struct" in MFC/VS2010

Tags: mfc

I'm a new person in MFC.

I have a question as follow:

I have a project, when I build application, it is successful and application run OK
However, when I open file `AdjustHorParameterDlg` (this is a file in project), VS2010 notice error `CDialog` "not a class or struct" :

```
class CAdjustHorParameterDlg : public CDialog
{
public:
    CString m_UnitName;
    //CString GetUnitName();
    //void SetUnitName( CString UnitName );
    int m_RequestedCenterPoint_Time;
    int m_SeledHMagni;
    CAdjustHorParameterDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // 標準のコンストラクタ
    CAdjustHorParameterDlg( CGraphsBase* pGraphs, CUIntArray* MagSelector, CString UnitOfXAxle,
        int InitialHMagni, int InitialDispPoint, CWnd* pParent = NULL ); 
    ~CAdjustHorParameterDlg();

    //{{AFX_DATA(CAdjustHorParameterDlg)
    enum { IDD = IDD_ADJHORIZONTALPARA };
    CEdit   m_RequestedCenterPointEdit;
    CListBox    m_HMagniListBox;
    int     m_HMagniListBoxIndex;
.....
```

Anyone tell me why?

Comment: So is this a compile error or just a bad intellisense notification?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code compiles successfully, you can ignore this. Sometimes Intellisense (the feature that looks for errors while you edit your code) won't recognise definitions that have been made in files included in your stdafx.h